# PC for Animation and Film software - Maya, Nuke, Houdini, Cubase

Tags: graphics-cards, pc, memory, processor, video-editing

I need a new PC, because my old one, doesn't hold up for my use anymore.
He's slow has a long loading time and crashes a lot...

I'll use it mainly for the following programmes:
Maya, Nuke, Houdini, Cubase, Photoshop, Premiere, After effects, Sketchup, Remake, Zbrush, DaVince...
Basically, the suites of the foundry, Autodesk, Adobe...

I don't want one with the minimum system requirements, but one that can run the above-mentioned software smoothly and can also do some simulations and render without crashing instantly.

It also should be able to output 3D, this is asked in my other question:
[What hardware is needed to output 3D?](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/8156/5579)

My Current PC:
Windows 7
8GB RAM
Intel Core i7 870 @ 2.93 GHz
64bit
NVIDIA GeForce GT 330

Would this be a suitable solution, or am I missing something or spending too much money on something I don't need?

https://pcpartpicker.com/list/ghd4sZ

My Budget is between $1500 and $2000.-

Comment: If you are willing to spend 5k+ USD you can get something quite beefy ;) But I guess you are on a smaller budget?

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking more in the range of 2K

Comment: Can you give some more specifics on what kind of work you're doing in these programs? To me it seems like you're being heavily GPU bottlenecked, but with a little RAM upgrade, you may be just fine.

Answer (score 2):

### Self-built option ~= $1600 (Prices fluctuate daily)

If you're comfortable with building your own systems (It's actually quite easy) I can easily fit it top of the line components for $1594.69. [Here's a PC Part Picker list](https://pcpartpicker.com/list/zyCvbX) that shows you where you can buy every single component. Also if you choose to tweak the build a bit more yourself, it has a compatibility filter to make sure everything fits. Specifically this build has:

- i7-8700k overclockable processor
- DDR4-3000 15 CAS latency Memory *(8700k supports 2666, but you can overclock it, you can buy a cheaper memory module otherwise, I would recommend the lowest timings)
- 300GB 10000RPM HDD
- Samsung 970 Evo 250GB M.2 SSD
- GeForce GTX 1080 8GB

I also gave you a Titanium Certified power supply for those energy savings, and included a thermal paste recommendation -Thermal Grizzly - Kryonaut - which is one of the best ceramic thermal pastes out there.

I cannot reccomend self-building enough, as **it is the most effective way to decrease cost of a PC**.

[Here's a link to the build in case you missed it above.](https://pcpartpicker.com/list/zyCvbX)

---

### [Pre-built option: ABS Battlebox Ultimate Bearcat $1,649.99](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16883102288R) (MSRP: $1,849.99)

[image]

Features high end components such as:

- NVIDIA GTX 1080 Ti 11 GB
- Intel Core i7 7th Gen 7700K
- 16 GB DDR4
- 2 TB HDD
- 240 GB SSD

This monster of a computer will remain competitive for years to come with it's top of the line features. While not as great a value as self-building should absolutely smoke your old hardware out of the water.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question [here](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/8233/pc-suggestion-for-video-editing/8255#8255) and I think [this](https://pcpartpicker.com/list/K3HGyf) would be great for apps you are using. I didn't include the OS and an HDD/SSD since you didn't really specify. You can also reduce the price by purchasing a cheaper PC Case.