# PC suggestion for Video editing

Tags: desktop, windows, video-editing

For work, I professionally edit videos. Right now I am using a Mac Book Pro, but I find it very slow and it's not fitting my workflow anymore.

My idea is to change my hardware and buy a Windows desktop.

What I need basically is a machine that will allow me to work on graphics and video editing. My computer needs to be fast in the rendering operations, analyze my video frame by frame and to compose it back.

I am working on raw files CinemaDNG (lossless formats), and I need a pc that can manage this huge amount of data. Each frame size is from 15 to 20 mega and we have 25 fps.

If it's possible, I would like to spend less than 2000 euros and I am mostly using AdobePremiere, Adobe After Effects and DavinciResolve

What computer will fit my needs right now?

Comment: Please specify a price-range, also pre-built PCs usually are less flexible but also nicer to use and also a little more expensive. Can you name the specific program(s) you are using for editing, this way we could potentially look up whether it's CPU / GPU / RAM / memory-speed intensive.

Comment: @rakwaht I have edited your question to include your comment. I have also removed the off-topic questions to focus on the pre-built computers.

Comment: Spend less then 2k what?

Comment: Sorry man I forgot to specify, I am thinking in euros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [this](https://pcpartpicker.com/list/MTPF7h) would be great(I included a monitor too since you didn't specify if you needed it), but I didn't include the storage since I don't know do you need 1TB or 5TB, you didn't specify it. Price without the monitor is ~1500$ which is ~1270 euros. You can take the nVidia 1080 if you are doing much complex work in DaVinciResolve but the 1070 should do the job.

Comment: Quite interesting, I didn't know this website where you can list pc parts like this. Really good suggestion

Comment: Swap the H115i for a Noctua NH-D15. Cheaper and better cooling performance. That 850W PSU is oversized, less will do.

Comment: I own a H115i so thats why I thought I should recommend it and yes 850W is a lot but again it won't hurt since I'm not sure what will he do with the PC. He can always change the parts tough :D